# Trouble receiving multiple emails with camel aggregator

Tags: java, email, apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I'm truly not sure how to word this correctly, but I'll try my best.

I want to send n emails to n recipients via a camel route and have those n recipients send approvals to the sender, which is done by using the world 'approve' in the subject, at which point, I'd trigger a process.

The first half of this task is done, as sending emails is a relatively simple task in Camel.  Receiving is as well.  My problem lies in the fact that I'd like to wait on these n emails to be received before continuing.

I'm using *this* code to attempt to do the latter half.

```
from("imaps://imap.gmail.com?username=emailaddress@gmail.com&" + 
"password=RAW(password)&searchTerm.subject=approve")
.aggregate(header("*"), new UseLatestAggregationStrategy())
.completionSize(2)
.process(myProcess);
```

I know this code won't do exactly what I'm asking for, but it's what I'm working with for now.  I'm getting *this* error when I drop the .jar into ServiceMix

```
org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException: Invalid correlation key. Exchange[MailMessage:
```

I've tried looking up the error, but I haven't gotten much that's helpful.  It's fairly obvious it's from either the header or the aggregation strategy, but again, I have yet to find anything useful for my situation.

Is there a better way to do this?  I feel like my problems are coming from not completely understanding the nuances of camel, so there may very well be an easier/better way to achieve this.  If not, what am I missing?

I apologize if I've left anything useful out.  Feel free to ask questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a constant as the correlation key if you want any message to be grouped together, for example:

```
.aggregate(constant(true), new UseLatestAggregationStrategy())
```

Comment: You're a life saver!  Thank you much!  Maybe I should just pick up a copy of your book, haha.

Comment: There is a 2nd ed on the way - if you buy you get 1st for free ;)